# Interpreting the flags for an adafruit BLE method to set a GATT characteristic

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-uno, spi, gatt

I am using the [Adafruit_BLE library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BluefruitLE_nRF51/blob/master/Adafruit_BLE.h) and the [Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI object](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BluefruitLE_nRF51/blob/master/Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI.h) to assign the Analog Output GATT characteristic to the [Adafruit Bluefruit LE SPI Friend](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2633).  I want to understand the format for setting these GATT flags.  In the [adafruit heartrate monitor sketch example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BluefruitLE_nRF51/blob/master/examples/heartratemonitor/heartratemonitor.ino) the Heart Rate Measurement GATT characterstic is set in line 123:

```
    /* Add the Heart Rate Measurement characteristic */
  /* Chars ID for Measurement should be 1 */
  Serial.println(F("Adding the Heart Rate Measurement characteristic (UUID = 0x2A37): "));
  success = ble.sendCommandWithIntReply( F("AT+GATTADDCHAR=UUID=0x2A37, PROPERTIES=0x10, MIN_LEN=2, MAX_LEN=3, VALUE=00-40"), &hrmMeasureCharId);
    if (! success) {
    error(F("Could not add HRM characteristic"));
  }
```

and the [GATT Heart Rate service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.heart_rate.xml) in line 115:

```
 /* Add the Heart Rate Service definition */
  /* Service ID should be 1 */
  Serial.println(F("Adding the Heart Rate Service definition (UUID = 0x180D): "));
  success = ble.sendCommandWithIntReply( F("AT+GATTADDSERVICE=UUID=0x180D"), &hrmServiceId);
  if (! success) {
    error(F("Could not add HRM service"));
  }
```

How do the flags addressed in GATTADDCHAR (UUID,Properties,Min_len,Max_len,value) correspond to the fields in the [Heart Rate Measurement GATT characteristic](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml): *Names,Field Requirement,Format,Minimum Value,Maximum Value,Additional Information*?

**(The GATTADDCHAR command explanation is found [here](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/introducing-the-adafruit-bluefruit-spi-breakout.pdf) in page 75 of the pdf)**

If I wanted to set the [Analog Output GATT characteristic](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.analog_output.xml) (or any other characteristic in general) how exactly would I call sendCommandWithIntReply(AT+GATTADDCHAR=...) for that to not give me an error? Some GATT characteristics have optional fields so I want to know exactly what I'm setting and how.

**In the end I simply want to read 16-bit bytes from a buffer and send them over bluetooth.**